# How to get the first element of a python list with a [start:stop:-1] slice?

Tags: python, list, slice

I have a list like this:

`list = ['a', 'b', 'c']`

I want the first element only, by using a list slicer that counts down.
That is:

`list[start:stop:-1]`

What do I set as *start* and *stop* to return exactly `['a']`?

My first intuition would be `list[0:-1:-1]`, but this returns an empty list.

Comment: (Don't shadow `list`, but...) `list[:1]`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You could do `my_list[-3::-1]` but that is very ugly.

Comment: *What do I set as start and stop to return exactly `['a']`?* - you probably know that `list[0]` returns `'a'`, and `list[0:1]` returns `['a']`. Then with negative indices: `list[-3]` returns`'a'`, and `list[-3:-2]` returns `['a']`. Where `-3` is actually `-len(list)+0`, and `-2` is `-len(list)+1`, from the original `[0:1]`. If you want it to count downwards, it can be `list[-3:-4:-1]`.

Comment: I found the correct notation: `list[0::-1]`